# replace values on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-features

I want o replace values in two attributes in a dataframe. `CheckIn` and `CheckOut`. '--' should be replaced by NA where one of these two attribute value is missing. I tried to put some conditional logic and apply functions but failed. finally i tried using for loop.

```
for(i in length(Empl.A)){
if((Empl.A$CheckIn[i]  == '--') & (Empl.A$CheckOut[i] == '--'))
{
  Empl.A$CheckIn[i] <- NA
  Empl.A$CheckOut[i] <- NA
}
}
```

[image]

please refer me to some useful resource on replacing values Or to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: look at your statement of `for` cycle: it should be `for(i in 1:now(Empl.A))`

Comment: btw, if you are reading this data from a csv file , you can fix this by passing  `na.strings = "--"` parameter to `read.csv()`

Comment: @R.S. but I don't want all '--' to be replace. Only those in both `checkIn` and `checkout` attributes

Comment: Why don't you want all `--` to be replaced? What possible use you have for them? `NA` can be used in various ways and have special dedicated function to handle them. You should definitly follow @R.S. suggestion if you ask me.

Comment: This make sense definitely.But I just had to keep `--` to replace this value with median in those rows where either of `checkin` or `checkout` is not missing [`--`]. Else the employee will be marked as absent if both `attributes` are `--`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a vectorized way without resorting to a loop.

```
> xy <- data.frame(a = 1:3, ci = c("a", "--", "--"), co = c("b", "--", "--"))
> xy
  a ci co
1 1  a  b
2 2 -- --
3 3 -- --
> xy[xy$ci == "--" & xy$co == "--", c("ci", "co")] <- NA
> xy
  a   ci   co
1 1    a    b
2 2 <NA> <NA>
3 3 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Got what needed.